# how to improve edge smoothness of an image rotated using pillow

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have this image

[image]

And I want to rotate it, and keep a smooth looking edge.

I have tried this approach below which adds some transparent borders to the image, to allow for the interpolation of the rotation to sample the transparent padding and the opaque image intensities when it renders the edge.

```
img = Image.open("sunset200x100.jpg")
im_array = np.asarray(img)
w, h = img.size
padding = 4
new_padded_size = (w+padding, h+padding)
img = img.convert('RGBA')  # converting to RGBA adds transparency to the areas that aren't opaque
img = ImageOps.pad(img, size=new_padded_size)
im_array_rgba_padded = np.asarray(img)
rotated_im = img.rotate(56, expand=True, resample=PIL.Image.BICUBIC)
as_array = np.asarray(rotated_im)
#rotated_im.show()
rotated_im.save("rotated_sunset200x100_padded_with_2px.png")
```

However, it doesn't seem to do interpolation on the left, and right sides of the image.  Inspecting the im_array_rgba_padded, I see that the first line, and last line of pixels have been made all black, however the left and right haven't got the same zero padding.
So the result ends up looking like this:-

[image]

wondering how I can get the padding into the left and right aswell, using the pad function, so that the left and right edges also look smooth ??  or why it is that the padding is not applied to the left and right aswell ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this change your code :

```
mg = Image.open("sunset200x100.jpg")
im_array = np.asarray(img)
w, h = img.size
print((w,h))
padding =4
new_padded_size = (w+padding, h+padding)
img = img.convert('RGBA')  # converting to RGBA adds transparency to the areas that aren't opaque
# img = ImageOps.pad(img, size=new_padded_size)
img = ImageOps.expand(img,new_padded_size,fill='black')
im_array_rgba_padded = np.asarray(img)
rotated_im = img.rotate(56, expand=True, resample=PIL.Image.BICUBIC)
as_array = np.asarray(rotated_im)
rotated_im.show()
```

this work in `windows10,python 3.9, pillow 8.3`.

for more information go to [this](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1948)  and [pillow/ImageOps](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html)